# I am noticing spike in CPU usage in the server, please see the image

Tags: linux, ubuntu, moodle

I am noticing spike in CPU usage in the server, please see the image. How do I know which is process is causing the CPU usage spike. I am trying to figure out why the spike is there. Is there a tool to know which process is causing the spike? Need to know if its a malicious process, the server is running Moodle application[image]

Comment: As it seems to happen in the same time start the check with scheduled processed in this time and around, backup, exports, searches, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. How do we check this, any command in the Ubuntu that will work track this down?

Comment: Moodle has its own cron scheduler so it can run anything. See https://docs.moodle.org/403/en/Scheduled_tasks

Comment: @truthtriumphs, learn more about `cron`. Also check the comment of AlexD.

Comment: What problem do you observe? Patterns in host resource utilization data are maybe interesting, but doesn't imply something users notice.

Comment: Users were not able to login. I increased the vCPU and RAM.  After the upgrade, had no incidents of user unable to login.